# How to make Drop Down List, if model is created based on Single Table Inheritance on Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have form which shown fields based on the Type of Publications you select. I have used Single Table Inheritance (according to this [link] http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance) to create Publication model (base model), and subclasses (book_chapter, book_whole, conference_article, journal_article). Fields of Publications model are as follows: type, author, title, year, publication, volume, issue, page, keywords, abstract, publisher, placeofpublication, editor, seriestitle, seriesvolume, seriesissue, issn, isbn, area, url, doi.

So, based on the Type that will be chosen (for instance book_chapter), I want to have particular fields of Publications.

I handled to create dropdown list with types, but when select the type and create publications the Type record do not saved on database. This is the code for type dropdown
list

```
  <%= f.label :type, :class => 'control-label' %>
  <div class="controls">
  <%= f.collection_select :type, Publication.order(:type), :id, :type, include_blank: true, :class => 'text_field' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Visar Kastrati, did my answer help ?

Comment: @Visar, if the answer below was of help to you, please accept (tick) it.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Are you sure type is permited as an accessible param in your controller</s>

```
def publication_params
  params.require(:publication).permit(:type)
end
```

Are you sure the values for your options in the select are the right ones ?

Why is your collection_select containing :id

```
<%= f.collection_select :type, Publication.order(:type), :id, :type, include_blank: true, :class => 'text_field' %>
```

instead of :type

```
<%= f.collection_select :type, Publication.order(:type), :type, :type, include_blank: true, :class => 'text_field' %>
```

---

Regarding your second question, the answer will rely on a javascript / client side implementation. 
Using jQuery you would implement something like this

```
# JS ($=jQuery)
# assuming your type select has id='type_select'
# assuming your fields inside your form have class 'field'
$('#type_select').change(function(event){
  current_type = $(e.target).val();
  $(e.target).parents('form').children('.field').each(function(el,i){
    if($.inArray($(el).attr('id'), form_fields_for(current_type)){
      $(el).show();
    }else{
      $(el).hide();
    }
  });
});

var form_fields_for= function(type){
  { book_chapter: [field1_id, field2_id, field3_id, field4_id], 
    book_whole: [field1_id, field2_id], 
    conference_article: [field1_id], 
    journal_article: [field1_id, field2_id, field3_id, field4_id, field5_id]
  }[type]; 
};
```

---

Another solution would be to set specific classes for each fields for each of your types:

If we take the same assumptions as above, you would have rails to show a form like this:

```
# pseudocode (html form)
form
  field1 class='book_chapter book_whole conference_article journal_article'
  field2 class='book_chapter book_whole journal_article'
  field3 class='book_chapter journal_article'
  ...
```

And then you would hide or show these specific classes

```
# JS ($=jQuery)
$('#type_select').change(function(event){
  current_type = $(e.target).val();
  $('.' + current_type).show();
  $(e.target).parents('form').children('.field').each(function(el,i){
    if(!$(el).hasClass(current_type)){
      $(el).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes it is 'def publication_params params.require(:publication).permit(:type, :author, :title, :year, :publication, :volume, :issue, :page, :keywords, :abstract, :publisher, :placeofpublication, :editor, :seriestitle, :seriesvolume, :seriesissue, :issn, :isbn, :area, :url, :doi)
end'

Comment: Yes it Helps, but want to have particular fields based on Type selection

Comment: Could you please explain (by updating your question) what my answer is lacking. What problem exactly wasn't fixed by my solution ?

Comment: Now the type is saved on my database. But, now based on the type that I select I don't want all field to show (for instance when I select Type: Book_Chapter), I want to have only some fields ( :author, :title, :year)